# Update DomNode pointers when inserting to another document

Tags: php, xml, dom, domdocument

I have a DOM structure which acts as a template for building a larger document. The template looks something like this (oversimplified example)

```
<book> // $cache[0]
    <data></data>
    <author></author> // $cache[1]
    <published>
    <company></company> // $cache[3]
    <date></date>
    </published>
    <blurb></blurb>
    <related></related> // $cache[2]
</book>
```

As you can hopefully see, I cache certain nodes within this template with the hope of doing expensive searches only once. (XPath is unusable in this situation due to the strict standards of the template.)

The above template will be added to a document looking like this:

```
<store>
    <genre>
    <computing>
        // Insert here
    </computing>
    <nature>
        // Again here
    </nature>
    </genre>
</store>
```

Basically, it can be inserted anywhere. The problem I can't figure out how to solve is how to keep or quickly update the cache points after the template has been inserted with methods like `appendChild` and `insertBefore`. The only solution I can see is to re-search the inserted node, but like I mentioned, this is expensive and certain tags which aided the first search will have been removed.

I find the insert points similar to any template engine, by iterating the dom and perform actions on certain handlers eg. `{{book}}` will request the above template be inserted.

The cache is simply an array of `DomNode`s but this can easily be changed if there is a better cross document method. I'm open to suggestions or pointers to code that have implemented similar.

Comment: `appendChild` & `insertBefore` a reference to the `DOMNode`, if you're storing an array of `DOMNode`s anyway, why not a reference to their insert-points? (An update would be a simple importNode & replaceChild)

Comment: @Wrikken In the example, `$cache[0]` can easily be updated from the return value of those methods. It's the child/grandchild nodes (`$cache[n]`) I'm having trouble with. They will still reference the nodes in the original document and I can't figure out how to update them without a re-search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by not caching the `DomNode` but rather a path to the node. I first looked at `getNodePath()` which returns an `XPath` to the node, but just looking at the returned path I saw that `XPath` must do a lot of branching under the hood. So I came up with this:

```
foreach ( $node->childNodes as $child ) {
    $index++;
    $path = $path . "->childNodes->item($index)";
}
```

Then after inserting the node into the second document, those cache points can be quickly referenced by

```
eval("\$node = \$node$path;");
```